# Accessing data in local drives from controller of grails application

Tags: csv, grails

I have my data in the form of a CSV file at the following location C:\xyz\data.csv in my system. How can I access this data from the controller of my grails application? Is it possible to do so? If yes, how? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for reading file (cvs, xml, img ,...) from controller

```
def csv = grailsAttributes.getApplicationContext().getResource("/data/data.csv").getFile()
```

try this for your case...

Comment: if you use `getResource` you should use a fully qualified url like `getResource('file:/data/data.csv')`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Comment: What is this location "/data/data.csv". Is it some folder inside the Grails application folder or can it be any location of the kind C:\xyz\data.csv on my local?

Comment: yz it is a folder inside grails app, in your case you have to specify your correct path...

Comment: @AnIsh Is it possible to use HQL for this CSV data? Until now, I was loading my data into MySQL and then using remoteFunction in GSP to pass params to controller inside the HQL to get the required data into the browser.With the CSV in the controller, will it still be possible?

Comment: The app throws an error when I tried doing what you suggested.The error is:unexpected char: '\' @ line 7, column 71.
   ationContext().getResource("D:\pgtyp.csv

Comment: @Nisha try this way getResource('file:/data/data.csv')

Comment: Error again - ERROR filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - Error when matching URL mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?]:null

Answer (score 0):

If your Grails application runs on the same system you can access the file like this.

```
class MyController {
    def myAction() {
       def myFile = new File('your path')
       def content = myFile.text
    }
}
```

If your webapp runs somewhere else (which is most likely your case) you can use the [file upload](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles).

Comment: How can I access 'content' in my GSP? Say, I want to print values for selected columns of my CSV to the console. How can I do that??